# Nothing happens in the shell

Tags: python-3.x

I run this in module and the shell show me a looong(in time) blank response. The final next_number never appears. Where is the problem?

```
def fibbonacci(fib):

next_number = []


for i in range(len(fib)):

    while next_number < [10]:
        next_number = [fib[i] + fib[i + 1]]
        fib.append(next_number)

print(next_number)
```

---

Yes, I want to compute the Fibonacci sequence. My problem is that when I passed to shell fibbonacci([1,2]), nothing happens.

Comment: Could you explain what is it you're trying to do? Because it sounds like whatever it is, it should be a hell lot simpler to implement than whatever you tried above.

Comment: `next_number < 10` In Python you can also compare ints to lists.

Comment: Earlier I thought you were doing some sum of terms in a precomputed Fibonacci sequence, which is why you were passing your function a list, but now I wonder if you're actually trying to compute the Fibonacci sequence itself.  Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

I made something out of what you wrote:

```
>>> def fibbonacci(length):
    fib = [1, 1]
    for i in range(length):
        next_number = fib[i] + fib[i + 1]
        fib.append(next_number)
    return fib

>>> fibbonacci(3)
[1, 1, 2, 3, 5]
```

note: `append` takes not a list but an element